# Why did a moderator delete this answer?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, moderation

I made an answer to a question here:

[How do I check the values of multiple elements (described by their IDs) using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800053/how-do-i-check-the-values-of-multiple-elements-described-by-their-ids-using-jq/16800133#16800133)

After realizing I hadn't actually answered the question (only really commented on syntactical mistakes, which were the first things I noticed before I evaluated what the code was attempting to accomplish), I edited my answer to be more complete.

I'm trying to understand why the answer itself was deleted - maybe the moderator has a valid reason that I haven't considered.  Or, maybe the moderator only saw the pre-edit version of the answer and deleted that.

Comment: I would assume the last explanation is the case. Your initial version seems to be a pair of comments asking for clarification rather than an answer. It might have been deleted because of flags to that effect.

Comment: @Laura Hm, what's up with that edit?

Comment: @Yannis [tag:status-completed] is really meant for bugs or technical requests. This question is asking for an explanation of a mod-action - I saw no reason to mark it status-completed.

Comment: @Laura I got it that this was your intention, but you also created  [meta-tag:status] in the process ;) That said, we do use [meta-tag:status-completed] for a lot of other stuff (on all Metas) and its tag wiki on MSO clearly encourages that: "A feature request that has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, _or a request has been processed._". If that's not OK anymore, we'll need some re-education.

Comment: @Yannis oh, I didn't even see that there was [tag:status] in my edit. That was definitely a bug - I did it from my iPad, and something clearly went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [original revision of your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16800133/1) didn't really address the question, focusing instead on more or less unrelated syntactical issues. I suspect this might have caused some people to flag it for moderator attention. Even though the "Not an answer" flag isn't really meant for this, it still happens.

However, the current revision of your answer looks fine. It should be undeleted.

Comment: Oh I'm certainly aware that the first version of my answer was a failure in terms of answering-the-question. But I also feel like the moderator should choose to delete based on the revised answer, not the original.  The delete was done some time after the edits were complete.

Comment: @nzifnab: Moderators are humans and they go through _lots_ of flags in a day; sometimes mistakes happen. I expect this will be resolved shortly.

Comment: @nzifnab Not to mention that in the moderator queue, the default view of a post is a truncated view (the first 35 words or so), if you've got what look to be comments in that part, it's reasonable for a moderator to mark 2 separate flags that said the post was not an answer as 'helpful' and delete the post.

Comment: "Even though the "Not an answer" flag isn't really meant for this" - I disagree, that seems like the kind of answer that definitely should be flagged as "not an answer" because those are merely comments.